# Self Scaling on Heroku

Tags: heroku, autoscaling

I understand the Heroku API's support for scaling, but how does one control which instance is killed when workers are scaled down?  Let's say that my worker (1 of 2) determines that its work is done and therefore wants to scale itself down.  If the worker exits, presumably Heroku detects that and starts up a new worker.  If the worker uses the API to scale itself, it may end up killing a second copy that is still busy instead of itself.  So how does a worker tell Heroku that it is voluntarily scaling down and to not start a new copy?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an add-on for that:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/adept-scale

Comment: Adept Scale is only for web processes currently.

Comment: That is correct; I'm looking for a method for scaling workers.  More specifically, how to control which worker is stopped when I scale down (e.g. from 2 workers to 1).

Answer (score 0):

See http://hirefire.io/ to automatically scale your workers on Heroku.